# SQL Server OR condition performance issue

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

Here is simpler version of one of the `SELECT` statement from my procedure:

```
select
    ...
from
    ...
where
    ((@SearchTextList IS NULL) OR 
     (SomeColumn IN (SELECT SomeRelatedColumn From #SearchTextListTable)))
```

`@SearchTextList` is just a `varchar` variable that holds a comma-separated list of strings. `#SearchTextListTable` is single column temp table that holds search text values.

This query takes 30 seconds to complete, which is performance issue in my application.

If I get rid of the first condition (i.e. if I remove OR condition), it takes just ONE second.

```
select
    ...
from
    ...
where
    SomeColumn IN (SELECT SomeRelatedColumn From #SearchTextListTable)
```

Can somebody please explain why this much difference?

What's going on internally in SQL Server engine?

Thanks.

Comment: Grab the post execution plans (the "actual execution plan") of each run and compare/contrast.

Comment: You are probably having a parameter sniffing problem. Try the workaround explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Thomas Stringer - I compared the execution plans, but to me it does not make sense. Basically the temp table #SearchTextListTable is going to be pretty small in this case. Execution plan with "OR" says 40% time consumption in #SearchTextListTable table scan, while the plan without "OR" says 0% for that.

Comment: Try changing your `Where ... IN` to a `Where ... Exists` and see what your execution plan looks like.

Comment: Don't know where 40% on scan of #Search table come from, perhaps it's doing this scan for every records instead of just one because it may be too dumb to understand that "@SearchTextList" will always be false. And even if so, it doesn't explain it quite well. Anyway where is the missing 60%?

Comment: Assuming you don't have multiple time the same value within #SearchTextListTable I would suggest to transform where clause "SomeColumn in .."  into a LEFT JOIN instead. Where clause should then be "WHERE @SearchTextList IS NULL OR AliasForSearchTextListTable.SomeRelatedColumn IS NOT NULL". This way, it won't mess around I believe.

Comment: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) very good detailed article explaining what is going on internally

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that the SQL is fast when you don't have the OR specified, I assume the table has index for `SomeColumn` and the amount of rows in #SearchTextListTable is small. When that is the case, SQL Server can decide to use the index for searching the rows.

If you specify the or clause, and the query is like this:

```
((@SearchTextList IS NULL) OR 
 (SomeColumn IN (SELECT SomeRelatedColumn From #SearchTextListTable)))
```

SQL Server can't create a plan where the index is used because the plans are cached and must be usable also when @SearchTextList is NULL.

There's usually 2 ways to improve this, either use dynamic SQL or recompile the plan for each execution.

To get the plan recompiled, just add `option (recompile)` to the end of the query. Unless this query is executed really often, that should be an ok solution. The downside is that it causes slightly higher CPU usage because the plans can't be re-used.

The other option is to create dynamic SQL and execute it with sp_executesql. Since in that point you know if @SearchTextList will be NULL, you can just omit the SomeColumn IN ... when it's not needed. Be aware of SQL injection in this case and don't just concatenate the variable values into the SQL string, but use variables in the SQL and give those as parameter for sp_executesql.

If you only have this one column in the SQL, you could also make 2 separate procedures for both options and execute them from the original procedure depending on which is the case.

Comment: The third option is to use UNion or UNion All instead of an OR clause. It will speed it up considerably if you can use UNION ALL

Comment: You could also use an If Else statement to run only the pertinent part of the code

Comment: @HLGEM This isn't really suitable for union because the OR clause is there to select all values in the table when no values are given in the variable

Comment: @HLGEM Using if-else might work, but there is a risk that you don't get correct plans for all the branches because query plan is made for all of them in the first execution, regardless if that part will be executed in that run or not in that case

Comment: Thanks everybody for comments and responses. Well the column "SomeColumn" actually does not have any index. I already converted my proc to IF..ELSE and it works great, but I just want to understand why SQL is delaying with OR...what's going on internally? Thanks.

Comment: @GreenBinary You should look at execution plan. One possibility is predicate pushdown -- the rows can be already filtered by the storage engine when it's just a simple where clause without an or.